# python-social-auth + mobile app

Tags: python, django, facebook, python-social-auth

I have a django app and I create API for mobile app. When it comes to user authentication I simple gets login + pass and do standard django login stuff. When user is logged in I generate a token, save it and provide to the mobile app.

Now it comes to Facebook and I would like to implement python-social-auth library. I do know how to implement it for standard web, it's really trivial. But I have no idea, how to implement it into my mobile API and how to incorporate there my token stuff.

Just thinking...
Is there a possibility to do programatical auth so I would be able to create API method and call the social auth stuff from there? But how about the "Allow access to XY app to your profile" page on facebook side?

Any advice helps. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Something like this http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/use_cases.html#signup-by-oauth-access-token ?

Comment: I will take a look and let u know. Thanks!

Comment: You was right. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation](http://python-social-auth-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use_cases.html#signup-by-oauth-access-token) describes how you can simply provide the `access_token` to authenticate/create a user.

```
from django.contrib.auth import login

from social.apps.django_app.utils import psa

# Define an URL entry to point to this view, call it passing the
# access_token parameter like ?access_token=<token>. The URL entry must
# contain the backend, like this:
#
#   url(r'^register-by-token/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$',
#       'register_by_access_token')

@psa('social:complete')
def register_by_access_token(request, backend):
    # This view expects an access_token GET parameter, if it's needed,
    # request.backend and request.strategy will be loaded with the current
    # backend and strategy.
    token = request.GET.get('access_token')
    user = request.backend.do_auth(request.GET.get('access_token'))
    if user:
        login(request, user)
        return 'OK'
    else:
        return 'ERROR'
```

Comment: I'm doing this but I want also a refresh token. I get the user perfectly signed up but no refresh_token even when the client defined `access_type=offline`