# Facebook OAuth login for mobile app with python-social-auth

Tags: django, facebook, xamarin, python-social-auth, xamarin.auth

I'm currently writing a mobile application in **Xamarin** and **Django** with [Python Social Auth](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/backends/facebook.html?highlight=facebook), my application requires personalisation so I decided to use Facebook authentication instead of allowing users to store a username/password combination due to the security implications.

This works fine when using a normal web browser due to it remembering states, but the tricky part comes when trying to use Xamarin. I tried using [Xamarin.Auth](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth), but this caused an error due to the fact that it expected an `access_token` in the response <sup>[[1]](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/blob/master/src/Xamarin.Auth/OAuth2Request.cs#L89)</sup>, which I'm unable to get from the Python Social Auth library as it expects a hard-coded redirect after completion <sup>[[2]](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/v0.2.19/social/actions.py#L96)</sup>, which in turn causes a conflict between both libraries.

I tried looking at the following example code, but this expects the mobile app to ALREADY have an access token (taken from a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434697/python-social-auth-mobile-app)):

```
from django.contrib.auth import login
from social.apps.django_app.utils import psa

# Define an URL entry to point to this view, call it passing the
# access_token parameter like ?access_token=<token>. The URL entry must
# contain the backend, like this:
#
#   url(r'^register-by-token/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$',
#       'register_by_access_token')

@psa('social:complete')
def register_by_access_token(request, backend):
    # This view expects an access_token GET parameter, if it's needed,
    # request.backend and request.strategy will be loaded with the current
    # backend and strategy.
    token = request.GET.get('access_token')
    user = request.backend.do_auth(request.GET.get('access_token'))
    if user:
        login(request, user)
        return 'OK'
    else:
        return 'ERROR'
```

If anyone has any experience with using Xamarin and Python Social Auth, it would be really appreciated if you could point me into the right direction with this.