# cannot import name setting error while importing psa

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I wanted mobile users to get google signin in my django application. And I followed this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28946767

And got this error

> File "/home/ghanshyam799/django_project_11/get_user_login/urls.py" in 
>    3. from .views import *
>
> File "/home/ghanshyam799/django_project_11/get_user_login/views.py" in 
>     9. from social.apps.django_app.utils import psa
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social/apps/django_app/utils.py" in 
>     1. from social_django.utils import load_strategy, load_backend, psa, setting, BackendWrapper, strategy
>
> Exception Type: ImportError at /
>   Exception Value: cannot import name setting

How can I work around this? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you post the whole error stack?

Comment: error came up from this line

"from social.apps.django_app.utils import psa"

Comment: Yes indeed I know, the issue is that you are importing `setting` and I really do not understand why you are importing `setting` from `social_django.utils`, so the whole stack trace or code or some context would help

Comment: I edited my question with detailed stack trace.. does this work?

Comment: Yes this help, I posted an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should import `psa` like `from social_django.utils import psa`
 in your `get_user_login/views.py` file
The package has been updated to change the package structure since the answer posted. Kindly check the updated documentation here http://python-social-auth-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use_cases.html#signup-by-oauth-access-token

Comment: Hey! thank you very much.. I want to upvote your help.. but don't have enough points for that.. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Never mind. Happy this works. I think the question poster can upvote the answers or at least mark it as accepted regardless the points. But good it works :)